# Are the green dots separable?

Tags: python-2.7, machine-learning, scikit-learn

[image: ![Kidney Disease after doing a PCA]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ki7aJ.jpg)

i have a dataset from which i want to predict the patient getting the disease. the graph below is the first step after:

1. scaling the 3 features
2. running the scikit learn's PCA routine
3. the original dataset has 25 features but for our exercise, we were asked to use only 3 features. these 3 features are then reduced to 2 thru PCA

When i look at this data, my first response is that the green dots (those not prone to kidney disease) are not separable.

Is my assumption correct?

Comment: thanks.....!! thats what i thhink too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be your PCA is not yielding the best features to separate your data. I would suggest using something like Random Forest or XGBoost where you can see feature importance easily and then use the best 3 features to try to classify the data.

Comment: Xgboost has become so important and widely used. Good recommendation.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to separate the dots.